# How can I add a JButton to my full screen java program

Tags: java, swing, window, jframe, jbutton

I have followed [thenewbostons java game tutorials on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLA331A6709F40B79D&feature=plcp) and managed to create a base class which will be in full screen mode using a screenmanager class. Well all works just fine, I can draw images and strings and so on, but how the heck can I add JButtons etc etc.

I have uploaded my code on pastie.org so you can see it :)

[Main.java](http://pastie.org/private/din8hclaikft57zfldsbma)

[Screen](http://pastie.org/private/wx2e9pdtu4r9iko22rvfg)

[BaseFrame [the abstract frame]](http://pastie.org/private/dafzw8bvg1qpxan6ghc5cw)

[Menu Frame [Inheritted from BaseFrame]](http://pastie.org/private/jzikicozcgvqkeywuvavaw)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider following code :
`import javax.swing.JButton;`
`import javax.swing.JFrame;`
`public class NewClass5 extends JFrame`
`{`
`JButton b=new JButton("button");`
    `NewClass5(){`
        `this.add(b);`
`this.setSize(200, 200);`
`this.setVisible(true);`
    `}`
    `public static void main(String a[]){`
`new NewClass5();`
    `}`
`}`

Answer (score 2):

Consider adding the button in ahead of time. Don't make it visible. Then when you want to give that option, setVisible(true). Unless you have many buttons that are dynamic and need to change on the fly or something, I think this should work.